# Swift - Slide menu covering complete screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have used [**this library**](https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/AKSwiftSlideMenu) to design slide menu in Swift language. I am facing one issue in this.

When slide menu opens, it covers complete screen. Ideally it should be on left side in half of the screen and remaining screen show show the background screen.

This how it looks.
[image]

Comment: Some of your current code would help more

Comment: https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/AKSwiftSlideMenu/blob/master/AKSwiftSlideMenu/BaseViewController.swift#L100 edit this line to have less x position

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by setting view width to half of the screen width.